# How to disable vertical scroll in Bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a form with a lot of items that cause the modal to extend to vertical scroll, but I don't want this. I've searched in question and answer and talked about background scroll and no modal-self.

```css
.modal {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;      
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="PopupModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">product defineا</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body contentForm" id="modelResult">
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="" style="text-align:right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100px; height: 38px;" onclick="submitform()">ok</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" style="width: 70px;height: 38px; ">cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Can you offer any help?

Comment: Can you show a little of your code?

Comment: You mean modal code ?

Answer (score 3):

I Resolve it by self.

```css
 .modal-body   {overflow-y: hidden!important}
```